# How to install mysql in offline

Tags: mysql

can anyone help me to know how to install MySQL in linux18.04(armhf 64 bit) offline? I got a few links but those links describe amd64.deb, please help me where can i get the mysqlserverarmhf.deb file and how to install it offline.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632898/how-to-install-mysql-server-in-ubuntu-offline

or is there any way that we can install MySQL through an sd card or we can do SCP MySQL server from one machine to another through SCP or any other?

Comment: You can manually download packages and install them. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)